# A triangle in a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

According to the following picture $E$ is the midpoint of $BD$ and $DC=BD$. If measure of $\angle EGF$ is equals to $90$ degrees then find the value of $\frac {DE} {EF}$.(point A is the center and BC is the diameter.)
[image]

My Attempt:if you connect F to B .We have $GF^2=FG×GB$.this is just what I can do.
note:only elemenry geometry is allowed.ِ

Comment: do you mean DC=DB?

Comment: Yes the post edited  thank you

Comment: Is A the center of the circle?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Why did you remove my edit?

Comment: do you mean $GF^2=EG×GB$ instead?

Comment: No I found that using pythagoras theorm varient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the mentioned equality {which should be $GF^2=EG×GB$), get $k = \dfrac {1}{5}$.

Result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: notice that $\frac{DE}{EF}=\frac{CE}{EB}$

Comment: Stop the downvotes, please, this is a good hint. The length of $CE$ can be found through Stewart's theorem or just the Pythagorean theorem. (+1) back.